# Двоеточие или тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания должен быть в предложении: "Подготовка начиналась с прочтения классики (—/:) вначале более легких произведений, потом более сложных".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение **с обобщающим словом,** выбор знака зависит от текста.

1) **Двоеточие.** Подготовка начиналась с прочтения классики: **вначале более легких произведений, потом более сложных**. Раскрытие содержания, наличие предупредительной паузы.

2) **Тире.** Подготовка начиналась с прочтения классики ― **вначале более легких произведений, потом более сложных**, затем перешли к современной литературе. Однородный ряд имеет присоединительный характер.